# changing attributes in PowerDesigner via vba-script

Tags: vba, powerdesigner

I have a data model in PowerDesigner. I wrote a vba-script that changes the description of a column to the value of the comment of the column. It does well. When I look at the column-properties I can see the new description. The problem is, that the new description does not appear in the table-overview. Only when I open the column-properties and close it with the ok-button, the new description appears in the table-overview. I have a lot of columns in my model, so... has it something to do with the object-hierarchy in PowerDesigner? My script:

```
option explicit
Dim kind, name, obj, c, a
kind = InputBox("(T)able or (V)iew")
name = InputBox("Enter name")
If kind = "T" Then
  Set obj = ActiveModel.FindChildByName(name, cls_table)
ElseIf kind = "V" Then
  Set obj = ActiveModel.FindChildByName(name, cls_view)
End If
For each c in obj.columns
  c.SetAttribute "Description", c.comment
Next
```

Comment: I don't know what it is you call "overview" in the context of PowerDesigner. Is it the symbols? If yes, how do you get the Table symbol to show the column description?

Comment: If you save the model, and open it back, does it fix the mentioned table-overview? (in case this is a problem of cascading the Description update to all related places)

Comment: Thanks for your comments. With "overview" I mean the window when you doubleclick a table. In this window there's a tab "columns". Here you can see the names, datatypes... comments and description of the columns. And no, saving and reopening doesn't fix it...

Comment: I have no idea, it works for me... In the list of Columns, it is `Description Text`which is shown, not `Short Description`, correct? Can you add a snapshot of this Columns list to be sure...
Also you could try using c.SetAttributeText instead of c.SetAttribute.